# External monitor - xrandr resolution doesn't work and problem with refresh rate

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor

I'm facing problem with xrandr to set new resolution and refresh rate. I only have the resolution 2560x1440 with refresh rate 33 mhz, if I try to increase the refresh rate I got the error below:

```
  Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

One thing that I tested was install Ubuntu 21.10 on VirtualBox and all the options of resolutions appears. View screenshot:
[Ubuntu from VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oRFp.jpg)
and screenshot "About" settings:
[Ubuntu from VirtualBox - About settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywInV.jpg)

I'm facing this problem with Pop!_os 21.04 and Ubuntu 21.10. I made a lot of research about this subject but, until now, I didn't get anything to fix the refresh rate.

Other information, I'm using HDMI cable version 2 that comes with the monitor (4k monitor).

When I did the research I saw a lot of people asking for response command "inxi -Fxxxrz".

So, below is the result:

```
denis@denis-pop-os:~$ inxi -Fxxxrz
System:    Kernel: 5.13.0-7620-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Desktop: GNOME 3.38.4 tk: GTK 3.24.25 
           wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 3.38.2.1 Distro: Pop!_OS 21.04 base: Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Vostro 3500 v: N/A serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0WMPGH v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.7.1 date: 07/05/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 39.9 Wh condition: 39.9/42.0 Wh (95%) volts: 13.0/11.4 model: BYD DELL 1VX1H16 type: Li-poly 
           serial: <filter> status: Full 
           Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Keyboard serial: <filter> charge: 55% (should be ignored) 
           rechargeable: yes status: Discharging 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 L2 cache: 12 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 44851 
           Speed: 666 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 666 2: 1178 3: 1090 4: 1279 5: 1086 6: 1974 7: 1298 
           8: 715 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 0000:00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:9a49 class ID: 0300 
           Device-2: Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus ID: 1-6:5 chip ID: 0c45:671e class ID: 0e02 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 compositor: gnome-shell driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1: 1366x768~60Hz 2: 2560x1440~33Hz s-dpi: 96 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Dell driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus ID: 0000:00:1f.3 
           chip ID: 8086:a0c8 class ID: 0401 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-7620-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 0000:00:14.3 chip ID: 8086:a0f0 
           class ID: 0280 
           IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Dell driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 
           bus ID: 0000:01:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 class ID: 0200 
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP) type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus ID: 1-10:7 
           chip ID: 8087:0aaa class ID: e001 
           Report: ID: hci0 state: down address: <filter> 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd v: 0.6 port: 4000 bus ID: 0000:00:0e.0 
           chip ID: 8086.9a0b rev: N/A 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 900.01 GiB (377.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: A-Data model: IM2P33F3A NVMe ADATA 256GB size: 238.47 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
           rotation: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 92103061 scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 172.3 GiB used: 121.39 GiB (70.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3 
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 497 MiB used: 356.4 MiB (71.7%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 dev: /dev/dm-0 mapped: cryptswap 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 60.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:     Packages: 1851 apt: 1824 flatpak: 7 snap: 20 
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hirsute stable
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-ubuntu-pop-hirsute.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu/ hirsute main
           2: deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu/ hirsute main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pop-os-apps.sources 
           1: deb http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system.sources 
           1: deb deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute hirsute-security hirsute-updates hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           2: deb deb-src X-Repolib-Default-Mirror: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute hirsute-security hirsute-updates hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
Info:      Processes: 364 Uptime: 1h 40m wakeups: 16 Memory: 11.43 GiB used: 5.29 GiB (46.3%) Init: systemd v: 247 runlevel: 5 
           Compilers: gcc: 10.3.0 alt: 10 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.01
```

The result of xrandr command:

```
denis@denis-pop-os:~/Documents$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3926 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1366x768+0+439 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  48.01  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected primary 2560x1440+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440_30.00  29.94  
   3928x1440_60.00  59.95  
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96  
   2560x1440_33.00  32.95* 
   2560x1440_41.00  40.97  
   2560x1440_55.00  54.93  
   2560x1440     54.93  
   2560x1440_54.97  54.97  
   3840x2160_30.00  30.00  
   4096x2160_60  60.00  
   3840x2160x60.00  60.00
```

As you can see I tried many sizes and many refresh rate but the only configuration that I had success were 2560x1440_30.00 and 2560x1440_33.00.

On Ubuntu I'm using X11. This screenshot is the about settings:
[Ubuntu About Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1KF3.png)

And below I tried to add new resolution with xrandr:

```
denis@denis-Vostro-3500:~$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
denis@denis-Vostro-3500:~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
denis@denis-Vostro-3500:~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440
denis@denis-Vostro-3500:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.00 +  48.01  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440     59.96  
  2560x1440_60.00 (0x7dc) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz
denis@denis-Vostro-3500:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 60
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
denis@denis-Vostro-3500:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 59.96
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you work in Wayland or X11 session ? Check it in Settings->About and [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1377211/edit) this information to your question.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański edited the question. On Ubuntu I'm using wayland and on Pop!_OS I'm using X11 and the problem occurs on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Pop_OS is unsupported by Canonical, you should consult with developers of this system.

In Ubuntu xrandr works in Xorg session.
To switch to Xorg : log out . Click gear in bottom-right corner and select `Ubuntu on Xorg`. Log in. Check a name of your video output , current video mode and allowed refresh rates :

```
 xrand
```

Then switch to some mode (example for Virtualbox):

```
 xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 75
```

Comment: Ok, I changed to Xorg during the login on Ubuntu and did the steps: cvt 2560 1440 and then create new mode with xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync and add this new mode to HDMI-1 xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_60.00 and when I tried to set the configuration I got error: xrandr -s 2560x1440_60.00 and the failure: Failed to change the screen configuration!

Comment: Option `-s` do not switch screen mode. Use command from my answer replacing Virtual1 to HDMI-1

Comment: If I use an resolution that I have from scratch, it works. For example, if I use this --output command to set full hd resolution with 75 rate or 60 rate, it works. But I want to increase my resolution because my monitor is 4k and from scratch I don't have this resolution from xrandr, so I created with --newmode and --addmode and then tried the output as you said. Got error: xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed. I'm updating those steps on question.

Comment: 1/ Ensure the graphics card can render 4k. Ensure the proper port is connected.  2/ Ensure your monitor is properly configured for 4k. Some monitors require the user to set this via buttons on the monitor. Ensure proper port.  3/ If your graph card is Nvidia ensure your system is configured for X11. Ensure you use the proper driver for the card.

Comment: 1- My graphic card is intel iris XE and according to intel specs, yes it render 4k. 2- The configuration is correct. I made tests with windows and with Ubuntu from VirtualBox and it works. 3- The graphic card is iris XE, not NVIDIA but the system is configured with Xorg (X11).

Comment: For 4K check , that your HDMI cable is HDMI-2.0

Comment: Yes, it is 2.0. And I tested the same cable with Windows and it works. And if I use VirtualBox it appears more resolutions. The problem is Ubuntu local installed on my SSD.